# Modified Cartestian Product of Two Lists Where Each Element in all Resulting Tuples is Distinct

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools, cartesian-product

If I have two lists, such as:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2]
```

And I want to get an output that looks like this:

```
new_list = [(1,0),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1)]
```

This is the Cartesian product minus the tuple that has the same element in both spots `(1,1)`. I could generate this by using `itertools` to get the Cartesian product and then looping back through to remove any tuples that do not have distinct elements, but that seems really inefficient.

Comment: It seems, that your desired output is not the Cartesian product of the two lists without the `(i, i)` tuples. Please edit your question. The headline and the desired output don't match.

Comment: I edited the headline. The desired output is a modification of the Cartesian product, as described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho list comprehensions are similarly fast as the `itertools.product` approach.

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [1, 2, 5]

x = [(i, j) for i in list1 for j in list2 if i != j]

print(x)
```

Though you didn't specify, if `list1` or `list2` elements are unique. If this is not the case, you should rather use

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 1]
list2 = [1, 2, 5, 2]

x = [(i, j) for i in set(list1) for j in set(list2) if i != j]
```

to prevent repetition of generated tuples.